# Are there a WebSocket node which can connect to an URL provided as an input and listen to messages?

Tags: websocket, node-red

As I can see, [Node-RED](http://nodered.org/) provides two WebSocket nodes which connect, subscribe or publish messages. And both of them use WebSocket URLs hardcoded in their properties. Is it possible to provide this URL from another node which outputs it in `msg`? Or maybe there exists a node which provides such functionality?

Comment: Just so that others know. Node-Red is supported currently from a [Google group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/node-red) so people probably won't get much response here. It isn't because we aren't friendly or helpful!